# Cassandra: Undefined column name tenant_id in table catalog.products

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 4.0.x with spring boot, I create my table with two primary key, one clustering and one partition. However, whenever I try to query some data I get an error saying that the column is not defined

```
Undefined column name tenant_id in table catalog.products; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name tenant_id in table catalog.products
```

**Here is my table definition and the executed query**:

```
cqlsh:catalog> DESCRIBE products ;

CREATE TABLE catalog.products (
    "TENANT_ID" text,
    "CODE" text,
    "CREATION_TS" timestamp,
    "EAN" text,
    "MANCODE" text,
    "MAXOQTE" int,
    "MINOQTE" int,
    "MODIFIED_TS" timestamp,
    "OFFLINEDATE" date,
    "ONLINEDATE" date,
    "P_TENANT_ID" text,
    "REFCODE" text,
    "SVHC" text,
    "TYPNAME" text,
    "TYPNAMESEO" text,
    "LOCDESCRIP" map<text, text>,
    "LOCNAME" map<text, text>,
    "LOCNAMESEO" map<text, text>,
    "PARENTS" set<text>,
    "SHORTDESC" map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ("TENANT_ID", "CODE")
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("CODE" ASC)
    AND additional_write_policy = '99p'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND cdc = false
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND extensions = {}
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99p';

CREATE INDEX pp_tenant_id_idx ON catalog.products ("P_TENANT_ID");

CREATE INDEX pr_ean_idx ON catalog.products ("EAN");

CREATE INDEX pr_mancode_idx ON catalog.products ("MANCODE");

CREATE INDEX pr_offlinedate_idx ON catalog.products ("OFFLINEDATE");

CREATE INDEX pr_onlinedate_idx ON catalog.products ("ONLINEDATE");

CREATE INDEX pr_refcode_idx ON catalog.products ("REFCODE");

CREATE INDEX pr_typname_idx ON catalog.products ("TYPNAME");

CREATE INDEX pr_typnameseo_idx ON catalog.products ("TYPNAMESEO");
cqlsh:catalog>
```

**Executed (generated) query**:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE TENANT_ID='19001' AND code='11015383' AND onlinedate <= toDate(now()) AND offlinedate >= toDate(now()) ALLOW FILTERING;
```

**Exception**:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM products WHERE  TENANT_ID=?  AND onlinedate <= toDate(now()) AND offlinedate >= toDate(now()) AND code=?  ALLOW FILTERING]; Undefined column name tenant_id in table catalog.products; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name tenant_id in table catalog.products
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:125) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.3.jar!/:3.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraAccessor.translate(CassandraAccessor.java:422) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.3.jar!/:3.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.translateException(CqlTemplate.java:764) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.3.jar!/:3.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:545) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.4.3.jar!/:3.4.3]
```

I thought it might be a compact storage issue but it is not the case:

```
cqlsh:catalog> alter table products drop compact storage;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot DROP COMPACT STORAGE on table without COMPACT STORAGE"
cqlsh:catalog>
```

Comment: Field names are case insensitive, unless in double quotes, you are specifying "TENANT_ID" in the table, but TENANT_ID in the query

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That solved the search issue. However, the insert query generated by Spring Data CassandraRepository contains the column names with quotes. Any idea to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I would not use double quotes on the field names - it's going to repeatedly catch things out as it is very unexpected / unusual to do.

Comment: Well, I recreated the tables without quotes in column names, but still CassandraRepository generate the insert query with quotes